# SXA Where to place custom module templates

Tags: sxa, helix

I am extending the Sitecore SXA SiteMetadata module to add some new functionality. My new module is called `Sitecore.XA.Feature.SiteMetadata.Custom`. To me the logical place to put the templates would be

```
/sitecore/templates/Feature/Experience Accelerator/SiteMetadataCustom
```

but I think I remember hearing that you should not modify or add templates into existing SXA folders. Is there a better place to put this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you will change any of SXA it will be overridden with next installation of SXA. So yes, you should not modify any of SXA items.

In order to create your custom extensions then you should create folder next to *Experience Accelerator* like this:

[image]

Of course, your template can inherit form SXA template.